# Open ZipFile but not the zip or jar inside

Tags: java, zip

I have to open a zip File which is straightforward, but inside this zip File there could be jar file. This jar should not be open. How could I resolve this?

```
for (Enumeration e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
        }
```

Comment: your jar file will be treated as a zip entry as the other files in zip. It will not automatically open until you not open it through your code.

Comment: your are so right...strange behaviours is only when only one jar is in a zip file, the zip file can't open.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the class Jar but I think you're looking for this. The operator instanceof returns true if the instance of the class is that object.

```
if (e.nextElement() instanceof jar)
    Jar ze = (Jar) e.nextElement();
else
     ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
```